# log to file so that appears the same as Log Viewer

Tags: jmeter

I would like to simplify the default jmeter log file output. I would like the format and debug level to be the same as what appears in Log Viewer when running jmeter from GUI (where it's simple to change log levels between DEBUG/INFO/ERROR, etc). I have tried tweaking the log4j2.xml file, but I'm not seeing the results change at all, much less exactly like Log Viewer. Here is what I am doing,

I run the following from command line (running no GUI mode):

```
./apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/jmeter -n -t MyTestPlan.jmx  -l MyTestPlan.log
```

I have the following logging options uncommented in log4j2.xml:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.junit" level="error" />
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="error" />
<Logger name="org.apache.jorphan" level="info" />
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log Viewer shows you the content of [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and skips the messages from the following classes:

- `org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils`
- `org.apache.jmeter.JMeter`

so if you turn the above guys off like:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils" level="off" />
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.JMeter" level="off" />
```

the contents of the *jmeter.log* file will be identical to what you see in the Log Viewer panel.

More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Answer (score 0):

You can also override logging using [-L](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

> Log level for specific categories or root logger can be overridden directly on the command line (instead of modifying log4j2.xml) as well. To do so, use the following options:

> **-L[category]=[priority]**
> Overrides a logging setting, setting a particular category to the given priority level. Since 3.2, it is recommended to use a full category name (e.g, org.apache.jmeter or com.example.foo), but if the category name starts with either jmeter or jorphan, org.apache. will be prepended internally to the category name input to construct a full category name (i.e, org.apache.jmeter or org.apache.jorphan) for backward compatibility.

In your case you can change apache log level as:

```
 -Lorg.apache=ERROR
```